# maven 3 webapp - No tests to run?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, maven-3

I've created a [webapp](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html) with maven 3:

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.my.app -DartifactId=myweb-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I didn't get the `src/test/java` folder, so I added it. As I understand, this doesn't violate the [Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

I wrote some JUnit tests, but when I tried to run them via `mvn test`, I get the "no tests to run" message:

> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- There are no tests to run.
>
> Results :
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0,
>   Skipped: 0

Of course, I can run these tests from the `run as` dialog, but i'd like maven to do it for me. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the tests that you wrote are in the src/test/java folder?

Comment: @lobster: Yes, I wrote them under src/test/java/com/my/webapp/SomeTests.java

Comment: And you're able to run that particular test through eclipse run as? Can you run "mvn clean install test" from the command line?

Comment: Thats strange. Do you see the compiled test classes under target/test-classes folder? If not, then your tests are not even getting compiled.

Comment: They are getting compiled, seems not to be recognized as tests though

Comment: Can you paste the test class declaration with a method in there? Are you annotating the test methods with @Test?

Comment: Can you post one of your tests? (along with full path?) - or/and look into/target/test-classes directory if anything is here (after running mvn test-compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default configuration of the [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) only includes test classes that follow a naming convention, see the default value of the [includes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) parameter:

```
<includes>
    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
    <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Some examples how to configure this can be found at [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: Indeed, Some of my tests where called *Tests.java. Changed it to *Test.java and worked :) Thank you very much.